# types may only contain one @Inject error, what's the problem?

Tags: android, dagger-2

when I use dagger2 like below codes, I don't understand why Error code don't work. when I don't use "@LoginNetworkSource private val scheduleModel: ScheduleModel", error occurs. So I tried excluding "annotation class LoginNetworkSource" code, but not working. why I can't only `fun provideIoDispatcher() = Dispatchers.IO` even though when I exclude

```
   @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    annotation class LoginNetworkSource
   @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginNetwork() : LoginNetwork {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url") 
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(provideOkhttp())
            .build()
            .create(LoginNetwork::class.java)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @ScheduleNetworkSource
    fun provideLoginModel(): LoginModel {
        return LoginModelImpl(provideLoginNetwork())

    }
```

*error message*

```
error: Types may only contain one @Inject constructor
    public DefaultScheduleRepository(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

*Working code*

```
class DefaultLoginRepository @Inject constructor(
    @LoginNetworkSource private val scheduleModel: ScheduleModel,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : LoginRepository {

}
```

*Error code*

```
class DefaultLoginRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : LoginRepository {

}
```

*ApplicationModule*

```
@Module(includes = [ApplicationModuleBinds::class])
object ApplicationModule {

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    annotation class LoginNetworkSource


    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideIoDispatcher() = Dispatchers.IO


    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkhttp() : OkHttpClient{
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)).build()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginNetwork() : LoginNetwork {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url") 
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(provideOkhttp())
            .build()
            .create(LoginNetwork::class.java)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @ScheduleNetworkSource
    fun provideLoginModel(): LoginModel {
        return LoginModelImpl(provideLoginNetwork())

    }

}

@Module
abstract class ApplicationModuleBinds {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindLoginRepository(repo: DefaultLoginRepository): LoginRepository
}
```

Comment: In your case if in kotlin you use constructor with default single parameter, it produces in bytecode with 2 constructors: one as is, other - with no argmunets that under the hood calls first one passing default value as first argument. When you mark such constructor with `@Inject` annotation - you will have 2 constructors both injectable, but dagger can't know which one should use - that's why you get such error message. In your case specify dagger explicitly haw to create  `DefaultLoginRepository`

Comment: I don't have to use one paramter injector like error code? the difference above code is jus t one param or two param, that is ioDispatcher or (ioDispatcher+scheduleModel)